# copy windows sharepoint services list items into another sharepoint server list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

My requirement I have one windows SharePoint services 2007 site list.
one SharePoint server 2013 site.

1. I have to copy data from windows SharePoint services 2007 site list
   to SharePoint server 2013 site list.
2. when ever data changes in windows SharePoint services 2007 site list
   data has to reflect into SharePoint server 2013 site list.

Could you please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can do this OOTB, due to two different version of SharePoint and separate farms. I am thinking, your options will be either some kind of custom development or use the BCS to get the data.

[Business Connectivity Services in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163782.aspx)

Comment: I got one idea, from windows SharePoint services 2007 site list download and store into sqldb , from that using powershell store into SharePoint server 2013 site list .Is it good?

Comment: as far as it works for you it is ok. Your limitation is due to two different version of SP. If you putting the document in SQL then why not BCS then you dont need to refresh it while pulling stuff from SQL.  But your solution i think need more monitoring.